# convert Float32 array to image in coreml

Tags: pytorch, type-conversion, coreml

I converted a deelplab v3 model from Pytorch to coreml and seeing the outputs as MultiArray, so I need to convert the output to image. I've been using many different advice (e.g. from coreml survival guide) but still haven't been successful. Could you anyone kindly help me out here? Thanks a lot.

FYI, this is the model spec from Python:

```
    spec desc is 
     input {
      name: "input.1"
      type {
           imageType {
            width: 513
            height: 513
           colorSpace: RGB
           }
          }
    }
    output {
     name: "1436"
     type {
          multiArrayType {
          dataType: FLOAT32
          }
     }
    }
```

In Xcode, the output the I printout in Xcode is "Float32 1 × 14 × 513 × 513 array", which I assume that 1 is the number of channels, 14 is the number of labels, and 513 x 514 is Width x Height. How can I convert this array into Int32 513 × 513 matrix or to an Image?

Thanks for your help!

Edited: I added my model output's structure compared with Apple's DeeplabV3's (visualized through Netron) below for your reference. Any guidance is appreciated!
1/ [My model output's architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V75VU.png)

2/ [Apple's DeeplabV3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfmCj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Images only have 1, 3 or 4 channels (grayscale, RGB, or RGBA). You have 14 channels, so you need to decide how those 14 channels map to colors.

Here is some demo code that shows a possible approach (also using DeepLab v3): https://github.com/hollance/SemanticSegmentationMetalDemo

Comment: Thanks for your advice. 14 is the number of labels (categories) in this model, whose purpose is background removal. I'm unsure about the number of channels. I assume it's 1 (the first number in the "Float32 1 × 14 × 513 × 513 array". In Apple's DeeplabV3, its output is already Int32 513 × 513 matrix when I printed out in Xcode, so I can apply Hollemans' CoreML Helpers to convert into image. However, in my model, the output is  "Float32 1 × 14 × 513 × 513 array", and I don't know how to convert this into Int32 513 × 513 matrix (similar to Apple's DeeplabV3). Do you have any advice? Thank you